# Can a rel that uses a CURIE be used for a single instance of an item and for a collection of those same items?

Tags: api, rest, hateoas, rel, curie

In my API, I have rels that look like this:

**For a single item**:

```
{
    ...
    _links: {
        ...,
        "api:activities/activity-resource": {
            "href": "..."
        }
    }
}
```

On another resource, I have multiple instances of `activity-resource`. How should I represent this? Is the following ok:

**For a collection**:

```
{
    ...
    _links: {
        ...,
        "api:activities/activity-resource": [{
            "href": "..."
        }, {
            "href": "..."
        }]
    }
}
```

It kind of makes sense since they are still instances of `activity-resource`, and a human being can look up the documentation for information on how to deal with those resources. However, now my API is a little inconsistent in that in certain representations the `api:activities/activity-resource` rel points to a single instance whereas in others it points to a collection.

I can make the argument a developer can figure out what he/she needs to do from the API documentation, but it helps to have a consistent API as well.

Comment: That's exactly how HAL handles it.  I think it is a reasonable approach.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like it is according to spec, but I anticipate fielding questions about consistency, as to how it is an array of links in one case, but a single link in another. I guess I can say "read the docs!", but I was wondering if there was a way to disambiguate this in some manner, since you don't end up with this ambiguity in the XML representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've encountered this same weakness in the HAL spec in practice.  A perfectly conforming client would treat the rel : {} format as a shorthand for rel : [{}], and so the switch form resource instance to instance should be no big deal.

but given that many HAL consumers just treat hal+json as straight json (ignoring the HAL semantics entirely) it gets worrisome.  I was working with some devs that assumed rel : {} implied am N-to-1 or 1-to-1 relationship..but that was not the case.  Once that bit us one time, I decided that we should always use rel : [{}] syntax if the rel could EVER be more than 1 as a hint to the consumer.  We consider a change in these rel multiplicities to be breaking compatibility because of this and favour new rels over lifting a single rel to multi as that is backwards compatible...then we consolidate in the next major version.